# Нужно ли это "то"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Из фильма 1978 года "Расписание на послезавтра":

*Вас не должно пугать **то,** что стихи ваши слабые — вы не профессионал...*

Сейчас стали злоупотреблять "то": где не нужно ни одного "то", ставят его, где нужно одно, например, "того", говорят "того, то что". А раньше вроде такого не было. Может, я чего-то не понимаю и это "то" там необходимо?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А мне кажется более заметной противоположная тенденция - упрощение речи за счет отбрасывания элементов, придающих ей *точность* ("представьте" вместо "представьте **себе**", "слизистая" вместо "слизистая оболочка" и т. п.). В приведенном примере "то" не может быть ошибкой (*что пугает? - **то**, что...*), хотя в *разговорной* речи может показаться излишним формализмом. При наличии "то" можно заметить в этом предложении согласие говорящего с тем, что стихи слабые (при отсутствии "то" высказывание более нейтрально, дескать возможно, они и не слабые на самом деле). Есть, конечно, случаи, когда "то" *невозможно*:

> Он не должен был **говорить** вам, **что** стихи ваши слабые...

Comment: Спасибо большое, Александр!

Comment: "то" невозможно, но в таких предложениях опускается не "то", а "о том": Он не должен был говорить вам о том, что стихи ваши слабые...

Answer (score 3):

**Вместо вступления**

Я не собиралась отвечать на этот вопрос, но сейчас считаю это необходимым, так как во втором ответе был упомянут **учебник Кустовой**. В нем подробно и точно описывается грамматика, но, судя по реакции на второй ответ, **грамматическая точность** востребованной не кажется. У меня на это другая точка зрения.

Я не буду подробно разбирать грамматику, которую  можно изучить  по книге, но обозначу основные моменты. Это выводы о том, как  можно **применить** полученные знания на практике.  Что мне не нравится в первом ответе? Там грамматический анализ фактически отсутствует, а выводы  по семантике кажутся субъективными. Поэтому ответ выглядит **неубедительным.**

1. При использовании  указательных слов в СПП можно  назвать **три варианта**:  (1) указательное слово  (коррелят) необходимо; (2) указательное слово запрещено; (3) допускаются оба варианта, причем один из них может считаться разговорным.  Все три варианта желательно соотнести **с грамматикой**.
2. **Когда мы категорически запрещаем коррелят?**

Сравним два предложения:
(1) ***Он сказал то, что все уже давно знают***. Это  местоименная связь (то – что), коррелят обязателен,  СПП с местоименно-определительным придаточным. Речь здесь идет о предмете.

(2) ***Он сказал, что все уже знают об этом.***  Коррелят запрещен,  и пользователи ясно ощущают это в речи: *Он сказал то, что все уже знали об этом* (это неверно!). Здесь вам непременно сделают замечание о неграмотности речи. Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным.

**Почему же мы так строги?** Это связано с наличием **парных вариантов** для местоимений  «то – что», которые обязательно надо различать. Практически коррелят **запрещен** для всех глаголов с изъяснительным значением, хотя  и  допускается для существительных (мысль о том, что).

3. А как обстоит дело **с глаголом «пугать»?** Это не изъяснительный глагол, но здесь присутствует та же пара местоимений:  «то – что».

(1) ***Меня пугает то, что происходит в доме.***  (2) ***Меня пугает то,  что в доме происходят странные вещи.***

В первом случае речь идет о предмете (местоименная связь), а во втором случае о ситуации (местоименно-союзная связь).  Но второе предложение  не изъяснительное, а **вмещающее изъяснительное**, когда коррелят **обязателен**. В этом случае придаточное раскрывает содержание местоименного слова «то».

Но мы готовы **отказаться от этого местоимения** и допускаем вариант с его пропуском:   (2)  ***Меня  пугает,  что в доме происходят странные вещи.***  Мы строим предложение по образцу обычного изъяснительного придаточного, как бы считая глагол «пугать» тоже изъяснительным.
Почему? Нас вполне устраивает, что мы различаем два типа предложения: (1) *Меня пугает то, что происходит в доме.*  (2) *Меня пугает,  что в доме происходят странные вещи.*

Так и получаются  **грамматические варианты**:  оформление предложения по двум **допустимым** образцам.  Ну а если так, то почему бы не придать им разные **семантические** оттенки?

5. **Ответ**

(1) ***Вас не должно пугать то, что стихи ваши слабые — вы не профессионал.***

Это оформление по образцу **вмещающего** изъяснительного  придаточного с **обязательным** коррелятом. **Значимость главного предложения подчеркнута**, так как в него включено указательное слово, а придаточное только раскрывает  значение уже названного местоимения.  **Смысл такой**: слабость стихов – это пока не самое важное (то, что пугает) , но, возможно,  надо обратить внимание на что-то другое.

(2) ***Вас не должно пугать, что стихи ваши слабые — вы не профессионал.***

Это оформление по образцу обычного  **изъяснительного**  придаточного без коррелята (глагол «пугать» приравнен к изъяснительным глаголам).  Фактически это как бы «косвенная речь», когда **вторая часть – это основное содержание**. Смысл такой:  Стихи ваши слабые, так как вы пока не профессионал, поэтому не следует этого пугаться.

**Вывод.** Я не претендую на правильность грамматического или семантического разбора, возможно, вы можете предложить  свой вариант. Здесь  важно **другое:** нужно отличать просто мнение от доказанного  каким-то образом решения.

Кустова Г. И. Синтаксис современного русского языка

[https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

Comment: Спасибо большое, Sharon!

Answer (score 1):

Синтаксис современного РЯ. Кустова 2013. п.64 (65 тоже поучительный, 60 основные понятия)

> Сложноподчиненные местоименно-соотносительные предложения строятся на
> основе двух соотносительных местоимений (указательное + союзное: то -
> что, такой-какой, так - как, там - где )
>
> Хотя в стандартной литературной речи коррелят **обязателен**, в
> разговорной речи и в стилистически сниженных конструкциях он может
> опускаться: Антон любил стянуть, что подвернется, но умнющий был на
> редкость. (**то, что подвернется**). Бери, сколько хочешь. (**столько,
> сколько хочешь**). Поступай, как велит совесть (**так, как велит**)

Любопытно, что в учебнике подчеркивают **обязательность то (коррелята) в литературном языке**. На мой взгляд это не так. Особое внимание уделяется связке **такой-как**. Поскольку слово **такой** имеет типизирующее значение, оно предполагает сравнение:

```
Торт был такой, какой мы хотели. // союзное слово
Торт был такой, как мы хотели.   // типизирующее местоимение + полноценный союз
```

При этом **как** может утрачивать знаменательность и превращаться в союз.

Если в главном предложении коррелят (о том) не является парным с союзным словом (что, как), которое при этом изъясняет сказуемое (говорить, что), то возникает дилемма между изъяснительным и местоименным СПП, не поддающаяся однозначной интерпретации.

```
Он не должен был говорить вам, что стихи ваши слабые...       // союз
Он не должен был говорить вам о том, что стихи ваши слабые... // коррелят + союз или союзное слово??
Он не должен был говорить вам о том, как слабы ваши стихи...  // коррелят + союзное слово
```

Это изъяснительное СПП. Коррелят "о том" не образует устойчивой связи с союзным словом (что, как). А значит можно считать союзное слово - союзом, на сколько я понимаю.

Comment: Я приветствую ваше желание изучать грамматику по хорошему вузовскому учебнику.  Здесь важно полностью проработать тему (например, все виды СПП), тогда вы сможете эффективно применять знания на практике.

Comment: *на сколько я понимаю* — здесь "насколько" лучше написать слитно.